# How does the “binary and” operator work in a while loop?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Here's a small program with an output of 7 (I thought the output was 6, since 126 & 127 = 6 using the binary system):

```
int main() {
    int x = 127, count = 0;

    while(x) {
        x &= (x - 1);
        count++;
    }

    printf("%d", count);
}
```

I don't why 1 was added to 6 (1 + 6 = 7).

Comment: It is printing `count`, not `x`. `x` is zero in the end of loop.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. do you know why count equals 7?

Comment: @Cascara *You* should. Grab a pencil and paper and write down what amounts to seven bitwise-and operations.

Comment: Or simply print each iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by 126 & 127 = 6? 126 & 127 is 126.

Comment: I only see the bit-wise and. But both work the same as outside a `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing variables in your explanation. What happens here is that the variable `count` will be incremented (with an original value of zero) while the value of `x` is *not* zero. At the same time, while the value of `x` is not zero, the bitwise-AND'ing of `x` and `x-1` is assigned to `x`.

Finally, **the printed result is *not* `x`, but `count`.**

And, according to my Python interpreter, the logic of this code ends with `x` having value `0` and `count` becomes `7`, thus `x` was AND-assigned with its predecessor `7` times before becoming zero.

This is what happens in pseudo-code with the `while` loop expanded:

```
x = 127;
c = 0;

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 127 & 126 thus x == 126;
    count += 1 thus count == 1;
}

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 126 & 125 thus x == 124;
    count += 1 thus count == 2;
}

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 124 & 123 thus x == 120;
    count += 1 thus count == 3;
}

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 120 & 119 thus x == 112;
    count += 1 thus count == 4;
}

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 112 & 111 thus x == 96;
    count += 1 thus count == 5;
}

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 96 & 95 thus x == 64;
    count += 1 thus count == 6;
}

x != 0 thus {
    x = x & x - 1 thus x == 64 & 63 thus x == 0;
    count += 1 thus count == 7;
}

x == 0, thus {
    count == 7, thus print(count) outputs "7";
}
```

BTW, ***126 & 127 == 0b1111110 & 0b1111111 == 0b1111110 == 126***.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze what your program is doing:

`x` starts with 127.

`while(x){` will loop *while* x is true. In this case, until `x` is `!=0`.

So, in your loop, you do `x &= (x-1);`, which is the boolean operation [`AND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), and then increment `count`:

```
    1111111  ; 127
  & 1111110  ; 126
    --------
    1111110  ; 126 ; count goes 1
  & 1111101  ; 125
    -------
    1111100  ; 124 ; count goes 2
  & 1111011  ; 123
    -------
    1111000  ; 120 ; count goes 3
  & 1110111  ; 119
    -------
    1110000  ; 112 ; count goes 4
  & 1101111  ; 111
    -------
    1100000  ; 96  ; count goes 5
  & 1011111  ; 95
    -------
    1000000  ; 64  ; count goes 6
  & 0111111  ; 63
    -------
    0000000  ; 0   ; count goes 7
```

Here, `x` goes to 0, and `while` stops.

Answer (score 0):

127 is 1111111 in the binary system, and 126 is 1111110. 127&126 will give 126. The while loop iterates until the result of x&(x-1) is zero. Here,the while loop iterates 7 times, and therefore, the count is incremented 7 times, after which x becomes zero. The answer is 7, as you are printing the value of count here.